# What's the difference between Splatfest Battle (Open) and Splatfest Battle (Pro?)

Tags: splatoon-3

During a Splatfest there are options for Splatfest Battle (Open) and Splatfest Battle (Pro). Both seem to have the same mode, stages, and description, so what's the difference between them?

[image: Splatfest Battle (Pro)]

Answer (score 4):

After a quick look into it, you could differentiate them this way:

Both do matchmaking trying to put you into games with players of similar skill level and relatively good connection to each other.

However, in **Open**, you're able to bring your friends with you (so this way you might bring a way weaker or way stronger player with you). In **Pro** you're restricted to queue solo and the game will strictly try to find something it considers fair and with you not being able to influence who you're playing with.

Comment: Having completed the Splatfest, they are also scored separately in team score calculations. Open is worth 15p while pro is worth 10p.

Comment: @Stevoisiak That's interesting. I'd actually respect the reverse, to encourage solo queueing, which would improve overall balance. Either they consider playing together more important or there's no skill based matchmaking anyway and it's really just two queues.

Answer (score 1):

- Clout is tracked separately
- Clout is not awarded to the losing team in Pro
- Synergy bonuses (matching clothes, etc.) are not calculated in Pro
- Your Splatfest Power is tracked in Pro, and the top 100 players for each team are shown in the Nintendo Switch Online app
- You cannot match with friends in Pro

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @Stevoisiak https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Splatfest

Comment: Your points 4 and 5 are not in your source, and I've hit x10 battles in Pro and never heard of the crown thing.

Comment: @Fredy31 The ingame manual that appears during a Splatfest states the "coveted Splatfest Top 100" as one of the perks of doing well in Pro. The crown actually isn't a perk of being in the top 100, it's [apparently from winning 100x/333x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/399445/295975). I've edited my response to remove these inaccuracies.

Comment: The Splatfest Top 100 can be found by going to the NSO app, clicking on Splatoon 3, clicking on Splatfest, choosing a Splatfest, and scrolling down to "Splatfest Top 100".