# What's that crown over Splatoon player's nametag?

Tags: splatoon-3

I've played a bunch of Turf wars this weekend because of the Splatfest, and I usually find players with a strange crown logo on their nickname, like ユーゼン in the screenshot below.

[image]

It could be related to the Splatfest, that "fish" looks like the stage on which the Deep Cut trio is dancing in the main square.

What's that, and how can you get it?

Comment: Almost commented "Hey, I recognize pinckerman" before realizing who posted the question.

Comment: @Stevoisiak LOL I wanted to be part of the question. No, I'm not an attention-seeker, mum!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's for winning the 100x/333x battle:

> Get a Crown for Winning the 100x/333x Battle.

> If you win the 100x/333x Battle, you can get a crown that will be shown above your name during the Splatfest. It is just a sign of winning the 100x/333x Battle and has no special effect.

[Source](https://gamewith.net/splatoon3/article/show/35461)

Comment: Good to know, never won a Festival Shell and never played a 100x battle in 2 days. Great.

Comment: Note that the second quote is correctly quoted as it was written - but it should say "333x" in the second sentence.

Comment: @TimmyJim - you can just tap Edit to fix stuff like that!

Comment: @Fattie of course - but thats _technically_ not what the quoted source says.  I guess I could do something like `100x/[333]x`.  I think that's one way of changing a quote and denoting that it was edited from the original source.  It is pretty clear though that they meant to say 333x based on context.  Eh not a big deal, lets just make it 333x.  I did use the leave Feedback button on the site and reported that its incorrectly written

Comment: I don't see any problem if you do a minor edit to fix an error in a quote, there's no reason to leave a wrong information if you know it's not correct.